# Applying command to window under cursor

Tags: vim-windows, scrolling

By using the following code

```
map <c-ScrollWheelUp> :resize +3^M
map <c-ScrollWheelDown> :resize -3^M
map <1-c-ScrollWheelUp> :resize +3^M
map <1-c-ScrollWheelDown> :resize -3^M
map <2-c-ScrollWheelUp> :resize +3^M
map <2-c-ScrollWheelDown> :resize -3^M
map <3-c-ScrollWheelUp> :resize +3^M
map <3-c-ScrollWheelDown> :resize -3^M
map <4-c-ScrollWheelUp> :resize +3^M
map <4-c-ScrollWheelDown> :resize -3^M
```

I can map control scrollwheel to zoom in and out of the current window.

But scrollwheel alone works in a subtly different way, it scrolls the window under the cursor up or down. How do I modify my code so it zooms the window under the cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:h getmousepos()` to get mouse last "click" (or "wheel") position and then `:h win_execute()` to execute a command in an arbitrary window. So it may look like

```
nnoremap <ScrollWheelUp>   <cmd>call win_execute(getmousepos().winid, "resize-1")<CR>
nnoremap <ScrollWheelDown> <cmd>call win_execute(getmousepos().winid, "resize+1")<CR>
```

Note: Not available in Neovim.

Comment: After upgrading to vim 8.2 this worked for me, thanks!